# Odd-degree polynomial is injective iff it has no relative extremum

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

Suppose $P(x)$ is an odd-degree polynomial with integer coefficients.

I want to prove that $P(x)$ is injective iff $P'(x)$ has no roots or has precisely one root. This is equivalent to that $P(x)$ has no relative extremum on any open interval.

I proved for a polynomial of degree $3$. In fact, if $\deg(P(x)) = 3$, then $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is injective iff $b^2 \le 3ac$.

However, I am stuck to prove that *if $P(x)$ has a relative extremum on a open interval $(a,b)$ with $a<b$, then $P(x)$ is not injective.* Of course, this is equivalent to prove that *if $P(x)$ is injective, it does not contain any relative extrema on any open interval $(a,b)$*.

My proof is as follows:

Suppose that $P(x)$ has no relative extremum on $(a,b)$, for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$. This is equivalent to saying that $|P(x)|$ has no relative maximum because the relative extremum, if any, is flipped with respect to the $x$-axis. By setting $h(x) = |P(x)|$, the derivative with respect to $x$ is $h'(x) = \text{sgn}(P(x)) \cdot P'(x)$, where $\text{sgn()}$ is the sign function (here we require that $P(x) \ne 0$). So, $h'(x) = 0$ iff $P'(x) = 0$. So, $P'(x)$ has the same algebraic sign whenever $x \ne x_0$, where $x_0 \in (a,b)$ with $P'(x_0)= 0$. Nevertheless, if $P'(x_0)=0$, it is unique. Also, if no $x_0$ exists, we are done. Hence, $P(x)$ is strictly monotonic. Therefore, $P$ is injective.

(After proving this, it wasn't easy to establish the other way around).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(EDITED) What you want to prove is not true.  Moreover, it's not equivalent to $P$ having no relative extremum on any open interval.  For example, try
$$P(x) = 3 x^5 - 10 x^3 + 15 x $$
This is injective, but
$$P'(x) = 15 x^4 - 30 x^2 + 15 = 15 (x^2-1)^2 $$
has two roots $x = \pm 1$.

What is true is that $P$ is injective if and only if all roots of $P'$ have even multiplicity.

Comment: But $P(x)$ is not a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: OK, multiply by $15$ and it does.  I'll edit.

Comment: So, is it true that if an odd-degree polynomial $P(x)$ has no relative extremum on any open interval, it's equivalent to be injective? Also, what do you mean by *even multiplicity*?

Comment: Yes, it is.  And that's true for any continuous function on $\mathbb R$.